# Java mock utils which contains construction method

Tags: java, mockito

I want to write unit test for my function, the function will call utils to generate url, and the utils will use other bean's contruction method, how should I handle it.

Below is some detail code, contains the core method, unit test method, and two utils method.

Appreciated for your idea.

```
public class WebClientServiceImpl implements WebClientService {
@Override
    public TokenDTO getToken(String authCode) {
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = generateCommonHttpEntity();
        entity.getBody().add("grant_type", OAuth2Constants.GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
        entity.getBody().add("redirect_uri", OAuth2StringUtils.getTokenRedirectURL());
        entity.getBody().add("code",authCode);

        return getTokenByPOST(entity);
    }
```

```
public class OAuth2StringUtils {
public static String getTokenRedirectURL() {
        return OAuth2CoreConfigProperties.getInstance().getTokenRedirectUrl();
    }
```

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="sso.config.oauth2")
public class OAuth2CoreConfigProperties implements InitializingBean {
public static OAuth2CoreConfigProperties getInstance() {
        return ssoOauth2CoreConfigProperties;
    }
```

```
@Spy
    @InjectMocks
    WebClientServiceImpl webClientService;

    @Mock
    OAuth2CoreConfigProperties config;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
@Test
    void should_return_token_given_auth_code_when_get_token() throws Exception {
        // given
        String authCode = "authCode";
        String accessToken = "accessToken";
        TokenDTO tokenDTO = TokenDTO.builder().access_token(accessToken).build();
        ResponseEntity<TokenDTO> response =  ResponseEntity.ok(tokenDTO);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String,String> formParameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        formParameters.add("client_id", "client_id");
        formParameters.add("client_secret", "client_secret");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(formParameters, headers);
        // when
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(config.getTokenEndpoint(),
                HttpMethod.POST,
                entity,
                TokenDTO.class)).thenReturn(response);
//        PowerMockito.when(OAuth2CoreConfigProperties.class, "getInstance").thenReturn(oAuth2CoreConfigProperties);
        Mockito.when(OAuth2StringUtils.getTokenRedirectURL()).thenReturn("token_redirect_url");
        // then
        TokenDTO result = webClientService.getToken(authCode);
        assertEquals(accessToken, result.getAccess_token());
    }
```

Comment: It's not a Utility class if it has non-static methods. Could you share the whole class? It's also strange to me that a real Utility class would require mocking at all.

Comment: @thinkgruen Updated above code, kindly have look. thanks

Comment: How does `ssoOauth2CoreConfigProperties` get created? If it is initialised by `@ConfigurationProperties` then you are using `OAuth2CoreConfigProperties` incorrectly. Just use `OAuth2CoreConfigProperties` as a spring bean so you can mock it during testing. If your utility class has to rely on something that is provided as a dependency by spring framework then it really isn't a utility class.

Comment: @madteapot yes, the method ```getTokenRedirectURL``` in my util class ```OAuth2StringUtils``` rely on ```OAuth2CoreConfigProperties.getInstance()```, so is there a way i can mock it, because ```OAuth2CoreConfigProperties``` use ```@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="sso.config.oauth2")```